# Adding array to listview

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listview

I have the following array: `T1History(T1HistoryLo) = ThisMoment + "," + Status + "," + lblPointValue.Text + "," + lblQuestion.Text + "," + userAnswer + "," + lblAnswer.Text + "," + Convert.ToString(QuestionNo)`

`T1History` = name of array
`T1HistoryLo` = Holds the next unused index
The rest are values to be added to the array separated by commas

I'm wondering how to add this array to a listview where each index in the array is a new row and each comma is another column.

Comment: Loop over array, split the "cell" at comma, then add first item of splitarray as "row" while other as subitems.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! @CruleD gave you a good hint on how to go about this. Try to code it, and if that does not work, post your code, people will be happy to help you get your code working. Good luck!

Comment: Why is this question tagged with VBA and VB.NET?  Please use only relevant tags and please READ THE DESCRIPTIONS of the tags to determine what's relevant.  The descriptions for those tags specifically state that they should not be used on questions for the other.

Comment: I wonder what happens if a value contains a comma... Can't you fill these values into an object (write an own class), so you don't have to parse them? You can still concatenate the values in its ToString() method or whereever you like, but I would also choose a better serialization. At least ```vbTab``` or something like that as delimiert, which you can ensure it cannot be entered by the user.